# Cropping specific area of map using Mapbox GL-JS

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, react

I am working on Mapbox. Is there any possible way to crop map image using Mapbox? Right now I am getting complete map as canvas but I just need to crop a specific area.

The thing which I want is to crop only that area where I am drawing polygon, I don't know whether it is possible or not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Draw a polygon and calculate its area</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.7.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.7.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<style>
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<style>
    .calculation-box {
        height: 75px;
        width: 150px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 40px;
        left: 10px;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
        padding: 15px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    p {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
</style>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@turf/turf@6/turf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-draw/v1.2.2/mapbox-gl-draw.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-draw/v1.2.2/mapbox-gl-draw.css" type="text/css">
<div id="map"></div>
<div class="calculation-box">
    <p>Click the map to draw a polygon.</p>
    <div id="calculated-area"></div>
</div>

<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoib21lcjA5IiwiYSI6ImNreWJkcjdmczBlYmMydm9mazYwMnBxMm8ifQ.yC2TC8C5hsIFb13-HgP_Pw';
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map', // container ID
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9', // style URL
        center: [-91.874, 42.76], // starting position [lng, lat]
        zoom: 12 // starting zoom
    });

    const draw = new MapboxDraw({
        displayControlsDefault: false,
        // Select which mapbox-gl-draw control buttons to add to the map.
        controls: {
            polygon: true,
            trash: true
        },
        // Set mapbox-gl-draw to draw by default.
        // The user does not have to click the polygon control button first.
        defaultMode: 'draw_polygon'
    });
    map.addControl(draw);

    map.on('draw.create', updateArea);
    map.on('draw.delete', updateArea);
    map.on('draw.update', updateArea);

    function updateArea(e) {
        const data = draw.getAll();
        const answer = document.getElementById('calculated-area');
        if (data.features.length > 0) {
            const area = turf.area(data);
            // Restrict the area to 2 decimal points.
            const rounded_area = Math.round(area * 100) / 100;
            answer.innerHTML = `<p><strong>${rounded_area}</strong></p><p>square meters</p>`;
        } else {
            answer.innerHTML = '';
            if (e.type !== 'draw.delete')
                alert('Click the map to draw a polygon.');
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: MapBox-GL-JS map]

Comment: You write "Right now I am getting complete map as canvas". Getting where? In what format would you like cropped map? Canvas? Please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/422895/edit) your question and add missing info.

Comment: Is there any way to crop the polygon? Getting as downloable image. I need the cropped image in base64 format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mapbox GL JS is not using `2d` context for canvas, but `webgl` context, so operation is not trivial. Logic goes like this:

- Polygon coordinates are converted to map pixel coordinates with `map.project` method.
- Drawn polygon is temporary deleted so that it does not mix with the clipped image.
- Get context of map canvas with `mapCanvas.getContext('webgl')`. For that to work, map option `preserveDrawingBuffer` has to be set to true.
- Convert `webgl` context to `2d` context.
- Actual size of Mapbox GL JS map canvas is bigger than it is shown (resized with style), so calculation of size factors is needed, since point coordinates returned by `map.project` method are not given for actual canvas, but for resized one.
- Calculate bounding box for clipped polygon.
- Translate canvas so that polygon bounding box is at `[0, 0]`.
- Create new empty canvas for clipped image and draw polygon on it and then clip context to this polygon.
- Draw map image to this clipped canvas.
- Create empty final canvas and draw only the clipped polygon to it.
- Download final canvas as image.

Since I'm not some canvas expert, code is probably not optimal, but it works. Below is relevant part of the code:

```js
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map', 
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9', 
  center: [-91.874, 42.76], 
  zoom: 12,
  preserveDrawingBuffer: true
});

function getPixels(ctx) {
  return ctx.readPixels
    ? getPixels3d(ctx)
    : getPixels2d(ctx)
}

function getPixels3d(gl) {
  var canvas = gl.canvas
  var height = canvas.height
  var width  = canvas.width
  var buffer = new Uint8Array(width * height * 4)

  gl.readPixels(0, 0
    , canvas.width
    , canvas.height
    , gl.RGBA
    , gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE
    , buffer
  )

  return buffer
}

function getPixels2d(ctx) {
  var canvas = ctx.canvas
  var height = canvas.height
  var width  = canvas.width

  return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data
}

function webglToCanvas2d(webgl, canvas2D) {
  var outCanvas = canvas2D ? canvas2D.canvas || canvas2D : document.createElement('canvas');
  var outContext = outCanvas.getContext('2d');
  var outImageData;

  webgl = webgl instanceof WebGLRenderingContext ? webgl : webgl.getContext('webgl') || webgl.getContext('experimental-webgl');

  outCanvas.width = webgl.canvas.width;
  outCanvas.height = webgl.canvas.height;
  outImageData = outContext.getImageData(0, 0, outCanvas.width, outCanvas.height);

  outImageData.data.set(new Uint8ClampedArray(getPixels3d(webgl).buffer));
  outContext.putImageData(outImageData, 0, 0);
  outContext.translate(0, outCanvas.height);
  outContext.scale(1, -1);
  outContext.drawImage(outCanvas, 0, 0);
  outContext.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

  return outCanvas;
}

function downloadCanvasAsImage(canvas, fileName){
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = fileName;
  link.href = canvas.toDataURL()
  link.click();
}

var points = [];
var savedPolygon;

function saveClipped() {
  var mapCanvas = map.getCanvas();
  var ctx = mapCanvas.getContext("webgl");
  var canvas2d = webglToCanvas2d(ctx);
  var ctx2d = canvas2d.getContext('2d');
  var clippedCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  clippedCanvas.width = mapCanvas.clientWidth;
  clippedCanvas.height = mapCanvas.clientHeight;
  var clippedCtx = clippedCanvas.getContext('2d');
  var factX = mapCanvas.clientWidth / mapCanvas.width;
  var factY = mapCanvas.clientHeight / mapCanvas.height
  var minX = points[0].x;
  var maxX = points[0].x;
  var minY = points[0].y;
  var maxY = points[0].y;
  for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
    if (points[i].x < minX)
      minX = points[i].x
    else if (points[i].x > maxX) {
      maxX = points[i].x
    }
    if (points[i].y < minY)
      minY = points[i].y
    else if (points[i].y > maxY) {
      maxY = points[i].y
    }
  }
  clippedCtx.scale(1/factX, 1/factY);
  clippedCtx.translate(-minX, -minY);
  clippedCtx.beginPath();
  clippedCtx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
  for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
    clippedCtx.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
  }
  clippedCtx.closePath();
  clippedCtx.lineWidth = 1;
  clippedCtx.stroke();
  clippedCtx.clip();
  clippedCtx.scale(factX, factY);
  clippedCtx.drawImage(canvas2d, 0, 0);
  var finalCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var finalWidth = (maxX - minX) / factX;
  var finalHeight = (maxY - minY) / factY;
  finalCanvas.width = finalWidth;
  finalCanvas.height = finalHeight;
  var finalCtx = finalCanvas.getContext('2d');
  finalCtx.drawImage(clippedCanvas, 0, 0, finalWidth, finalHeight, 0, 0, finalWidth, finalHeight);
  downloadCanvasAsImage(finalCanvas, 'clipped-image.png');
  draw.add(savedPolygon);
}

function updateArea(e) {
  if (e.features[0].geometry.type == 'Polygon') {
    savedPolygon = e.features[0];
    var polygonId = e.features[0].id;
    var coords = savedPolygon.geometry.coordinates[0];
    coords.forEach(function(coord) {
      points.push(map.project(coord));
    });
    draw.delete(polygonId);
    setTimeout(saveClipped, 100);
  }
  const data = draw.getAll();
  const answer = document.getElementById('calculated-area');
  if (data.features.length > 0) {
    const area = turf.area(data);
    const rounded_area = Math.round(area * 100) / 100;
    answer.innerHTML = `<p><strong>${rounded_area}</strong></p><p>square meters</p>`;
  } else {
    answer.innerHTML = '';
  }
}
```

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: It's quite explanatory and in depth. When i tested i am getting an empty cropped polygon image(without map) after downloading it. The example image you showed is exactly what i want to achieve.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that map option `preserveDrawingBuffer` has to be set to `true`. See modified answer.

Comment: The solution you mentioned works fantastic . Just a last question is it possible to get the cropped polygon image as a tiff format. Becuase image is getting blurred when i am zooming it.

Comment: Format of image wouldn't change anything, since image quality depends on resolution, and resolution cannot be better than screen resolution at the time of image clipping.

Comment: So it means it is not possible to extract the cropped area of polygon as tiff fie.

Comment: No, you can't do it directly, but you can use some library for that, like for example https://github.com/motiz88/canvas-to-tiff.